# (Py) Spark - Group by user over a window of time

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm processing lots of log files and I'd like to move the job to Spark, but I can't figure out how to aggregate events over an event-based time window the way I can easily in Pandas.

Here's exactly what I want to do:

For a log file (simulated below) of users who have experienced some event, I'd like to go back in time, seven days, and return aggregates for all other columns.

Here it is in Pandas. Any ideas how to port this to PySpark?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'event':[0,1,0,0,0,1], 'other':[12, 20, 16, 84, 11, 15] , 'event_date':['2015-01-01 00:02:43', '2015-01-04 00:02:03', '2015-01-10 00:12:26', '2015-01-01 00:02:43', '2015-01-06 00:02:43', '2015-01-012 18:10:09']})
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])
df
```

Gives:

```
    event  event_date           other  user_id
0   0      2015-01-01 00:02:43  12     1
1   1      2015-01-04 00:02:03  20     1
2   0      2015-01-10 00:12:26  16     1
3   0      2015-01-01 00:02:43  84     2
4   0      2015-01-06 00:02:43  11     2
5   1      2015-01-12 18:10:09  15     2
```

I'd like to group this DataFrame by user_id, then exclude any row from aggregation where the row is older than seven days from the "event".

In Pandas, like so:

```
def f(x):
    # Find event
    win = x.event == 1

    # Get the date when event === 1
    event_date = list(x[win]['event_date'])[0]

    # Construct the window
    min_date = event_date - pd.DateOffset(days=7) 

    # Set x to this specific date window
    x = x[(x.event_date > min_date) & (x.event_date <= event_date)]

    # Aggregate other
    x['other'] = x.other.sum()

    return x[win] #, x[z]])


df.groupby(by='user_id').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Giving the desired output(one row per user, where event_date corresponds to event==1):

```
    event   event_date          other   user_id
0   1       2015-01-04 00:02:03 32      1
1   1       2015-01-12 18:10:09 26      2
```

Anyone know where to start getting this result in Spark?

Answer (score 3):

Rather SQLish but you can do something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

# With raw SQL you can use datediff but it looks like it is not
# available as a function yet
def less_than_n_days(n):                                                       
    return udf(lambda dt1, dt2: 0 <= (dt1 - dt2).days < n, BooleanType())

# Select only events
events = df.where(df.event == 1).select(
        df.event_date.alias("evd"), df.user_id.alias("uid"))

(events
    .join(df, (events.uid == df.user_id) & (events.evd >= df.event_date))
    .where(less_than_n_days(7)(col("evd"), col("event_date")))
    .groupBy("evd", "user_id") 
    .agg(sum("other").alias("other"))
    .withColumnRenamed("evd", "event_date"))
```

Unfortunately we cannot include `less_than_n_days` in `join` clause because `udf` can access only columns from a single table. Since it doesn't apply to built-in `datediff` you may prefer raw SQL like this:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
events.registerTempTable("events")

sqlContext.sql("""
    SELECT evd AS event_date, user_id, SUM(other) AS other
    FROM df JOIN events ON
        df.user_id = events.uid AND
        datediff(evd, event_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 6
    GROUP by evd, user_id""")
```